# Git push зависает

Tags: git, push

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу залить проект на удаленный репозиторий,но при этом Git push зависает и не выдает никакой ошибки

Comment: попробуйте выполнять `git push` с ключом `--progress`. В консоли будет выводиться больше информации о ходе выполнения

Comment: @Герман Борисов  Уже пробовал,консоль ничего не выводит