# Завис git push в MINGW64 консоли

Tags: git

Просмотрел похожие проблемы, но ответа не нашел, хотя таких вопросов много. В одном месте было, что просто само заработало через несколько дней.))
По существу. Зарегистрировался в GitHub, создал репозиторий, клонировал его на локальный компьютер, сделал 2 коммита и хочу отправить их на сервер.
Выполняю git push и... консоль висит.)) То есть после набора команды нажимаю enter, курсор переходит на новую строку и все. Ждал полтора часа, потом закрыл.))

Comment: запустите push  с параметром -v, оно должно в консоль выдавать больше сообщений, может поймем, что там. А также, как именно клонировали - через ssh или http?

Comment: [дубликат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1300739/178576)

Comment: очень похоже. Но там так и не прояснилась ситуация

Comment: По https так и не получилось решить проблему. Переделал на SSH - заработало.

Comment: вот оно - https подключение. Если провайдер решил забанить github (а в некоторых странах такое случается), то кто знает, как оно будет работать